# How to define Matlab Bar3 DisplayName for individual surface objects

Tags: matlab

I have a series of histograms being plotted along side each other in a bar3 plot. I'd like to take advantage of the plot browser to turn on and off various histograms so I can do side by side comparisons. You can see from the properties Inspector that I've altered the display name for one such surface, the third, that is being updated in the legend but not in the property browser.

There's also a misregistration of the colors you see in the legend to that of the actual plot. The legend is accurate only when I have all surfaces checked for display.

I'm using MATLAB Version 7.13.0.564 (R2011b)

Thanks for helping

[image: Bar3 example of misregistered colors between legend and what's toggled for display]

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the legend off and on with `legend('off')` followed by `legend('show')`.  Try also `legend('toggle')`.

Comment: No luck with either of these unfortunately. Thanks for trying though.